# How to get plain text response using AJAX using Dojo

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, dojo, get

I created a sample web service that returns a plain/text value (you can access it [HERE (it's safe)](http://jalbautista.xtreemhost.com/givename.php)). I just created something similar to those that I will use in my project. I tried using Dojo's xhrGet method but it didn't work. I had read about The Same Origin Policy, so I tried dojo.io.script, but then it still didn't work. I'm a newbie in Dojo and Ajax so I really don't know what to do next. How will I do this in Dojo (or even in plain javascript)? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: "Didn't work" is unhelpful. What exactly didn't work? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: actually, I don't know how it works. I just followed the steps in the tutorial. Sorry :(

Comment: Are you able to debug your code using FireBug or equivalent?

Comment: yes. I saw that it creates a script tag in the head, with src equals to the url I gave. The script contains the value I need. Now my problem is how to get it :(

Answer (score 0):

#### To retrieve via javascript get

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://jalbautista.xtreemhost.com/givename.php", false );
            xmlHttp.send( null );
            alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    </script>
```

#### To retrieve via dojo (cross domain)

Use dojo.xd.js for cross domain build (or use the one provided by google see below)
If you're going to use JSONP your script should spit out something like

```
doSomething("AUTO\\x-BautistaJ");
```

Script should look something like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.io.script");
    function doSomething(data){
            alert(data);
    }
    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
    dojo.io.script.get( {url : "http://jalbautista.xtreemhost.com/givename.php",
                     callbackParamName : 'doSomething',
                     preventCache :true,
                     load : function(response, ioArgs) {
                                console.log("Response", response + ' ' + ioArgs);
                                return response;
                            },
                      error : function(response, ioArgs) {
                                console.log("Response error : ", response + ' '
                                              + ioArgs);
                               return response;
                            }
                     }
                   );
    });
    </script>
```